# Cert-Manager Challenge pending, no error in MIC (Azure DNS)

Tags: azure-aks, cert-manager, azure-dns, aad-pod-identity

I can't get TLS to work. The CertficateRequest gets created, the Order too and also the Challenge. However, the Challenge is stuck in pending.

```
Name:         test-tls-secret-8qshd-3608253913-1269058669
Namespace:    test
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
API Version:  acme.cert-manager.io/v1
Kind:         Challenge
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2022-07-19T08:17:04Z
  Finalizers:
    finalizer.acme.cert-manager.io
  Generation:  1
  Managed Fields:
    API Version:  acme.cert-manager.io/v1
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:finalizers:
          .:
          v:"finalizer.acme.cert-manager.io":
    Manager:      cert-manager-challenges
    Operation:    Update
    Time:         2022-07-19T08:17:04Z
    API Version:  acme.cert-manager.io/v1
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:ownerReferences:
          .:
          k:{"uid":"06029d3f-d1ce-45db-a267-796ff9b82a67"}:
      f:spec:
        .:
        f:authorizationURL:
        f:dnsName:
        f:issuerRef:
          .:
          f:group:
          f:kind:
          f:name:
        f:key:
        f:solver:
          .:
          f:dns01:
            .:
            f:azureDNS:
              .:
              f:environment:
              f:hostedZoneName:
              f:resourceGroupName:
              f:subscriptionID:
        f:token:
        f:type:
        f:url:
        f:wildcard:
    Manager:      cert-manager-orders
    Operation:    Update
    Time:         2022-07-19T08:17:04Z
    API Version:  acme.cert-manager.io/v1
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:status:
        .:
        f:presented:
        f:processing:
        f:reason:
        f:state:
    Manager:      cert-manager-challenges
    Operation:    Update
    Subresource:  status
    Time:         2022-07-19T08:25:38Z
  Owner References:
    API Version:           acme.cert-manager.io/v1
    Block Owner Deletion:  true
    Controller:            true
    Kind:                  Order
    Name:                  test-tls-secret-8qshd-3608253913
    UID:                   06029d3f-d1ce-45db-a267-796ff9b82a67
  Resource Version:        4528159
  UID:                     9594ed48-72c6-4403-8356-4991950fe9bb
Spec:
  Authorization URL:  https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/authz-v3/131873811576
  Dns Name:           test.internal.<company_id>.com
  Issuer Ref:
    Group:  cert-manager.io
    Kind:   ClusterIssuer
    Name:   letsencrypt
  Key:      xrnhZETWbkGTE7CA0A3CQd6a48d4JG4HKDiCXPpxTWM
  Solver:
    dns01:
      Azure DNS:
        Environment:          AzurePublicCloud
        Hosted Zone Name:     internal.<company_id>.com
        Resource Group Name:  tool-cluster-rg
        Subscription ID:      <subscription_id>
  Token:                      jXCR2UorNanlHqZd8T7Ifjbx6PuGfLBwnzWzBnDvCyc
  Type:                       DNS-01
  URL:                        https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/chall-v3/131873811576/vCGdog
  Wildcard:                   false
Status:
  Presented:   false
  Processing:  true
  Reason:      azure.BearerAuthorizer#WithAuthorization: Failed to refresh the Token for request to https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscription_id>/resourceGroups/tool-cluster-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/dnsZones/internal.<company_id>.com/TXT/_acme-challenge.test?api-version=2017-10-01: StatusCode=404 -- Original Error: adal: Refresh request failed. Status Code = '404'. Response body: getting assigned identities for pod cert-manager/cert-manager-5bb7949947-qlg5j in CREATED state failed after 16 attempts, retry duration [5]s, error: <nil>. Check MIC pod logs for identity assignment errors
 Endpoint http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fmanagement.core.windows.net%2F
  State:  pending
Events:
  Type     Reason        Age                From                     Message
  ----     ------        ----               ----                     -------
  Normal   Started       59m                cert-manager-challenges  Challenge scheduled for processing
  Warning  PresentError  11s (x7 over 51m)  cert-manager-challenges  Error presenting challenge: azure.BearerAuthorizer#WithAuthorization: Failed to refresh the Token for request to https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscription_id>/resourceGroups/tool-cluster-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/dnsZones/internal.<company_id>.com/TXT/_acme-challenge.test?api-version=2017-10-01: StatusCode=404 -- Original Error: adal: Refresh request failed. Status Code = '404'. Response body: getting assigned identities for pod cert-manager/cert-manager-5bb7949947-qlg5j in CREATED state failed after 16 attempts, retry duration [5]s, error: <nil>. Check MIC pod logs for identity assignment errors
 Endpoint http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fmanagement.core.windows.net%2F
```

It says to check the MIC pod logs, however, there are no errors logged:

```
I0719 08:16:52.271516       1 mic.go:587] pod test/test-deployment-b5dcc75f4-5gdtj has no assigned node yet. it will be ignored
I0719 08:16:52.284362       1 mic.go:608] No AzureIdentityBinding found for pod test/test-deployment-b5dcc75f4-5gdtj that matches selector: certman-label. it will be ignored
I0719 08:16:53.735678       1 mic.go:648] certman-identity identity not found when using test/certman-id-binding binding
I0719 08:16:53.737027       1 mic.go:1040] processing node aks-default-10282586-vmss, add [1], del [0], update [0]
I0719 08:16:53.737061       1 crd.go:514] creating assigned id test/test-deployment-b5dcc75f4-5gdtj-test-certman-identity
I0719 08:16:53.844892       1 cloudprovider.go:210] updating user-assigned identities on aks-default-10282586-vmss, assign [1], unassign [0]
I0719 08:17:04.545556       1 crd.go:777] updating AzureAssignedIdentity test/test-deployment-b5dcc75f4-5gdtj-test-certman-identity status to Assigned
I0719 08:17:04.564464       1 mic.go:525] work done: true. Found 1 pods, 1 ids, 1 bindings
I0719 08:17:04.564477       1 mic.go:526] total work cycles: 392, out of which work was done in: 320
I0719 08:17:04.564492       1 stats.go:183] ** stats collected **
I0719 08:17:04.564497       1 stats.go:162] Pod listing: 20.95µs
I0719 08:17:04.564504       1 stats.go:162] AzureIdentity listing: 2.357µs
I0719 08:17:04.564508       1 stats.go:162] AzureIdentityBinding listing: 3.211µs
I0719 08:17:04.564512       1 stats.go:162] AzureAssignedIdentity listing: 431ns
I0719 08:17:04.564516       1 stats.go:162] System: 71.101µs
I0719 08:17:04.564520       1 stats.go:162] CacheSync: 4.482µs
I0719 08:17:04.564523       1 stats.go:162] Cloud provider GET: 83.123547ms
I0719 08:17:04.564527       1 stats.go:162] Cloud provider PATCH: 10.700611864s
I0719 08:17:04.564531       1 stats.go:162] AzureAssignedIdentity creation: 24.654916ms
I0719 08:17:04.564535       1 stats.go:162] AzureAssignedIdentity update: 0s
I0719 08:17:04.564538       1 stats.go:162] AzureAssignedIdentity deletion: 0s
I0719 08:17:04.564542       1 stats.go:170] Number of cloud provider PATCH: 1
I0719 08:17:04.564546       1 stats.go:170] Number of cloud provider GET: 1
I0719 08:17:04.564549       1 stats.go:170] Number of AzureAssignedIdentities created in this sync cycle: 1
I0719 08:17:04.564554       1 stats.go:170] Number of AzureAssignedIdentities updated in this sync cycle: 0
I0719 08:17:04.564557       1 stats.go:170] Number of AzureAssignedIdentities deleted in this sync cycle: 0
I0719 08:17:04.564561       1 stats.go:162] Find AzureAssignedIdentities to create: 0s
I0719 08:17:04.564564       1 stats.go:162] Find AzureAssignedIdentities to delete: 0s
I0719 08:17:04.564568       1 stats.go:162] Total time to assign or update AzureAssignedIdentities: 10.827425179s
I0719 08:17:04.564573       1 stats.go:162] Total: 10.82763016s
I0719 08:17:04.564577       1 stats.go:212] *********************
I0719 08:19:34.077484       1 mic.go:1466] reconciling identity assignment for [/subscriptions/<subscription_id>/resourceGroups/tool-cluster-rg/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/cert-manager-dns01] on node aks-default-10282586-vmss
I0719 08:22:34.161195       1 mic.go:1466] reconciling identity assignment for [/subscriptions/<subscription_id>/resourceGroups/tool-cluster-rg/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/cert-manager-dns01] on node aks-default-10282586-vmss
```

The "reconciling identity" output gets repeated afterwards. Up to this point, I was able to handle my way through error messages, but now I have no idea how to proceed. Anyone got any lead what I'm missing?

Following my terraform code for the infrastructure.

```
terraform {
  cloud {
    organization = "<company_id>"
    workspaces {
        name = "tool-cluster"
    }
  }
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = ">= 3.6.0, < 4.0.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

data "azurerm_client_config" "default" {}

variable "id" {
    type = string
    description = "Company wide unique terraform identifier"
    default = "tool-cluster"
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "default" {
  name     = "${var.id}-rg"
  location = "westeurope"
}

resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "default" {
  name                = "${var.id}-aks"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.default.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.default.name
  dns_prefix          = var.id

  default_node_pool {
    name            = "default"
    node_count      = 1
    vm_size         = "Standard_D4_v5"
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  role_based_access_control_enabled = true
  http_application_routing_enabled = true
}

resource "azurerm_dns_zone" "internal" {
  name = "internal.<company_id>.com"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.default.name
}

resource "azurerm_user_assigned_identity" "dns_identity" {
  name                = "cert-manager-dns01"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.default.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.default.location
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "dns_contributor" {
  scope                = azurerm_dns_zone.internal.id
  role_definition_name = "DNS Zone Contributor"
  principal_id         = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.dns_identity.principal_id
}
```

I've added the roles "Managed Identity Operator" and "Virtual Machine Contributor" in the scope of the generated resourcegroup of the cluster (MC_tool-cluster-rg_tool-cluster-aks_westeurope) and "Managed Identity Operator" to the resource group of the cluster itself (tool-cluster-rg) to the kubelet_identity.

Code for the cert-manager:

```
terraform {
  cloud {
    organization = "<company_id>"
    workspaces {
      name = "cert-manager"
    }
  }
  required_providers {
    kubernetes = {
      source  = "hashicorp/kubernetes"
      version = ">= 2.12.0, < 3.0.0"
    }
    helm = {
      source = "hashicorp/helm"
      version = ">= 2.6.0, < 3.0.0"
    }
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = ">= 3.6.0, < 4.0.0"
    }
  }
}

data "terraform_remote_state" "tool-cluster" {
  backend = "remote"
  config = {
    organization = "<company_id>"
    workspaces = {
      name = "tool-cluster"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

provider "kubernetes" {
  host = data.terraform_remote_state.tool-cluster.outputs.host

  client_certificate     = base64decode(data.terraform_remote_state.tool-cluster.outputs.client_certificate)
  client_key             = base64decode(data.terraform_remote_state.tool-cluster.outputs.client_key)
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(data.terraform_remote_state.tool-cluster.outputs.cluster_ca_certificate)
}

provider "helm" {
  kubernetes {
    host = data.terraform_remote_state.tool-cluster.outputs.host

    client_certificate     = base64decode(data.terraform_remote_state.tool-cluster.outputs.client_certificate)
    client_key             = base64decode(data.terraform_remote_state.tool-cluster.outputs.client_key)
    cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(data.terraform_remote_state.tool-cluster.outputs.cluster_ca_certificate)
  }
}

locals {
  app-name = "cert-manager"
}

resource "kubernetes_namespace" "cert_manager" {
  metadata {
    name = local.app-name
  }
}

resource "helm_release" "cert_manager" {
  name       = local.app-name
  repository = "https://charts.jetstack.io"
  chart      = "cert-manager"
  version    = "v1.8.2"
  namespace  = kubernetes_namespace.cert_manager.metadata.0.name

  set {
    name  = "installCRDs"
    value = "true"
  }
}

resource "helm_release" "aad_pod_identity" {
  name       = "aad-pod-identity"
  repository = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/aad-pod-identity/master/charts"
  chart      = "aad-pod-identity"
  version    = "v4.1.10"
  namespace  = kubernetes_namespace.cert_manager.metadata.0.name
}

resource "azurerm_user_assigned_identity" "default" {
  name = local.app-name
  resource_group_name = data.terraform_remote_state.tool-cluster.outputs.resource_name
  location = data.terraform_remote_state.tool-cluster.outputs.resource_location
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "default" {
  scope = data.terraform_remote_state.tool-cluster.outputs.dns_zone_id
  role_definition_name = "DNS Zone Contributor"
  principal_id = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.default.principal_id
}

output "namespace" {
  value = kubernetes_namespace.cert_manager.metadata.0.name
  sensitive = false
}
```

and the code for my issuer:

```
terraform {
  cloud {
    organization = "<company_id>"
    workspaces {
      name = "cert-issuer"
    }
  }
  required_providers {
    kubernetes = {
      source  = "hashicorp/kubernetes"
      version = ">= 2.12.0, < 3.0.0"
    }
    helm = {
      source = "hashicorp/helm"
      version = ">= 2.6.0, < 3.0.0"
    }
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = ">= 3.6.0, < 4.0.0"
    }
  }
}

data "terraform_remote_state" "tool-cluster" {
  backend = "remote"
  config = {
    organization = "<company_id>"
    workspaces = {
      name = "tool-cluster"
    }
  }
}

data "terraform_remote_state" "cert-manager" {
  backend = "remote"
  config = {
    organization = "<company_id>"
    workspaces = {
      name = "cert-manager"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

provider "kubernetes" {
  host = data.terraform_remote_state.tool-cluster.outputs.host

  client_certificate     = base64decode(data.terraform_remote_state.tool-cluster.outputs.client_certificate)
  client_key             = base64decode(data.terraform_remote_state.tool-cluster.outputs.client_key)
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(data.terraform_remote_state.tool-cluster.outputs.cluster_ca_certificate)
}

provider "helm" {
  kubernetes {
    host = data.terraform_remote_state.tool-cluster.outputs.host

    client_certificate     = base64decode(data.terraform_remote_state.tool-cluster.outputs.client_certificate)
    client_key             = base64decode(data.terraform_remote_state.tool-cluster.outputs.client_key)
    cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(data.terraform_remote_state.tool-cluster.outputs.cluster_ca_certificate)
  }
}

locals {
  app-name = "cert-manager"
}

data "azurerm_subscription" "current" {}

resource "kubernetes_manifest" "cluster_issuer" {
  
  manifest = yamldecode(templatefile(
    "${path.module}/cluster-issuer.tpl.yaml",
    {
      "name" = "letsencrypt"
      "subscription_id" = data.azurerm_subscription.current.subscription_id
      "resource_group_name" = data.terraform_remote_state.tool-cluster.outputs.resource_name
      "dns_zone_name" = data.terraform_remote_state.tool-cluster.outputs.dns_zone_name
    }
  ))
}
```

Also, the yaml:

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: ${name}
spec:
  acme:
    email: support@<company_id>.com
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: ${name}
    solvers:
      - dns01:
          azureDNS:
            resourceGroupName: ${resource_group_name}
            subscriptionID: ${subscription_id}
            hostedZoneName: ${dns_zone_name}
            environment: AzurePublicCloud
```

Finally, my sample app:

```
terraform {
  cloud {
    organization = "<company_id>"
    workspaces {
      name = "test-web-app"
    }
  }
  required_providers {
    kubernetes = {
      source  = "hashicorp/kubernetes"
      version = ">= 2.12.0, < 3.0.0"
    }
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = ">= 3.6.0, < 4.0.0"
    }
    azuread = {
      source = "hashicorp/azuread"
      version = ">= 2.26.0, < 3.0.0"
    }
  }
}

data "terraform_remote_state" "tool-cluster" {
  backend = "remote"
  config = {
    organization = "<company_id>"
    workspaces = {
      name = "tool-cluster"
    }
  }
}

provider "azuread" {}
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

provider "kubernetes" {
  host = data.terraform_remote_state.tool-cluster.outputs.host

  client_certificate     = base64decode(data.terraform_remote_state.tool-cluster.outputs.client_certificate)
  client_key             = base64decode(data.terraform_remote_state.tool-cluster.outputs.client_key)
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(data.terraform_remote_state.tool-cluster.outputs.cluster_ca_certificate)
}

locals {
  app-name = "test"
  host     = "test.${data.terraform_remote_state.tool-cluster.outputs.cluster_domain_name}"
}

resource "azurerm_dns_cname_record" "default" {
  name = local.app-name
  zone_name = data.terraform_remote_state.tool-cluster.outputs.dns_zone_name
  resource_group_name = data.terraform_remote_state.tool-cluster.outputs.resource_name
  ttl = 300
  record = local.host
  
}

resource "azuread_application" "default" {
  display_name = local.app-name
}

resource "kubernetes_namespace" "default" {
  metadata {
    name = local.app-name
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_secret" "auth" {
  metadata {
    name = "basic-auth"
    namespace = kubernetes_namespace.default.metadata.0.name
  }
  data = {
    "auth" = file("./auth")
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_deployment" "default" {
  metadata {
    name      = "${local.app-name}-deployment"
    namespace = kubernetes_namespace.default.metadata.0.name

    labels = {
      app = local.app-name
    }
  }

  spec {
    replicas = 1

    selector {
      match_labels = {
        app = local.app-name
      }
    }

    template {
      metadata {
        labels = {
          app = local.app-name
          aadpodidbinding = "certman-label"
        }
      }

      spec {
        container {
          image = "crccheck/hello-world:latest"
          name  = local.app-name

          port {
            container_port = 8000
            host_port      = 8000
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_service" "default" {
  metadata {
    name      = "${local.app-name}-svc"
    namespace = kubernetes_namespace.default.metadata.0.name
  }

  spec {
    selector = {
      app = kubernetes_deployment.default.metadata.0.labels.app
    }

    port {
      port        = 8000
      target_port = 8000
    }
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_ingress_v1" "default" {
  metadata {
    name      = "${local.app-name}-ing"
    namespace = kubernetes_namespace.default.metadata.0.name
    annotations = {
      "kubernetes.io/ingress.class" = "addon-http-application-routing"
      "cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer" = "letsencrypt"
      # basic-auth
      "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-type" = "basic"
      "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-secret" = "basic-auth"
      "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-realm" = "Authentication Required - foo"
    }
  }

  spec {
    rule {
      host = local.host

      http {
        path {
          path = "/"

          backend {
            service {
              name = kubernetes_service.default.metadata.0.name

              port {
                number = 8000
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    rule {
      host = trimsuffix(azurerm_dns_cname_record.default.fqdn, ".")

      http {
        path {
          path = "/"

          backend {
            service {
              name = kubernetes_service.default.metadata.0.name

              port {
                number = 8000
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    tls {
      hosts = [ trimsuffix(azurerm_dns_cname_record.default.fqdn, ".") ]
      secret_name = "${local.app-name}-tls-secret"
    }
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_manifest" "azure_identity" {
  manifest = yamldecode(templatefile(
    "${path.module}/azure_identity.tpl.yaml",
    {
      "namespace" = kubernetes_namespace.default.metadata.0.name
      "resource_id" = data.terraform_remote_state.tool-cluster.outputs.identity_resource_id
      "client_id" = data.terraform_remote_state.tool-cluster.outputs.identity_client_id
    }
  ))
}

resource "kubernetes_manifest" "azure_identity_binding" {
  manifest = yamldecode(templatefile(
    "${path.module}/azure_identity_binding.tpl.yaml",
    {
      "namespace" = kubernetes_namespace.default.metadata.0.name
      "resource_id" = data.terraform_remote_state.tool-cluster.outputs.identity_resource_id
      "client_id" = data.terraform_remote_state.tool-cluster.outputs.identity_client_id
    }
  ))
}
```

The two identity yaml:

```
apiVersion: "aadpodidentity.k8s.io/v1"
kind: AzureIdentity
metadata:
  annotations:
    # recommended to use namespaced identites https://azure.github.io/aad-pod-identity/docs/configure/match_pods_in_namespace/
    aadpodidentity.k8s.io/Behavior: namespaced
  name: certman-identity
  namespace: ${namespace} # change to your preferred namespace
spec:
  type: 0 # MSI
  resourceID: ${resource_id} # Resource Id From Previous step
  clientID: ${client_id} # Client Id from previous step
```

and

```
apiVersion: "aadpodidentity.k8s.io/v1"
kind: AzureIdentityBinding
metadata:
  name: certman-id-binding
  namespace: ${namespace} # change to your preferred namespace
spec:
  azureIdentity: certman-identity
  selector: certman-label # This is the label that needs to be set on cert-manager pods
```

edit: reformatted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to solve it with http application routing, so I installed my own ingress and instead of aad-pod-identity I installed ExternalDNS with Service Principal. The terraform code for that:

```
locals {
  app-name = "external-dns"
}

resource "azuread_application" "dns" {
  display_name = "dns-service_principal"
}

resource "azuread_application_password" "dns" {
  application_object_id = azuread_application.dns.object_id
}

resource "azuread_service_principal" "dns" {
  application_id = azuread_application.dns.application_id
  description = "Service Principal to write DNS changes for ${data.terraform_remote_state.tool-cluster.outputs.dns_zone_name}"
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "dns_zone_contributor" {
  scope = data.terraform_remote_state.tool-cluster.outputs.dns_zone_id
  role_definition_name = "DNS Zone Contributor"
  principal_id = azuread_service_principal.dns.id
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "rg_reader" {
  scope = data.terraform_remote_state.tool-cluster.outputs.dns_zone_id
  role_definition_name = "Reader"
  principal_id = azuread_service_principal.dns.id
}

resource "kubernetes_secret" "external_dns_secret" {
  metadata {
    name = "azure-config-file"
  }
  data = { "azure.json" = jsonencode({
    tenantId        = data.azurerm_subscription.default.tenant_id
    subscriptionId  = data.azurerm_subscription.default.subscription_id
    resourceGroup   = data.terraform_remote_state.tool-cluster.outputs.resource_name
    aadClientId     = azuread_application.dns.application_id
    aadClientSecret = azuread_application_password.dns.value
    })
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_service_account" "dns" {
  metadata {
    name = local.app-name
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_cluster_role" "dns" {
  metadata {
    name = local.app-name
  }
  rule {
    api_groups = [ "" ]
    resources = [ "services","endpoints","pods", "nodes" ]
    verbs = [ "get","watch","list" ]
  }
  rule {
    api_groups = [ "extensions","networking.k8s.io" ]
    resources = [ "ingresses" ]
    verbs = [ "get","watch","list" ]
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_cluster_role_binding" "dns" {
  metadata {
    name = "${local.app-name}-viewer"
  }
  role_ref {
    api_group = "rbac.authorization.k8s.io"
    kind = "ClusterRole"
    name = kubernetes_cluster_role.dns.metadata.0.name
  }
  subject {
    kind = "ServiceAccount"
    name = kubernetes_service_account.dns.metadata.0.name
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_deployment" "dns" {
  metadata {
    name = local.app-name
  }
  spec {
    strategy {
      type = "Recreate"
    }
    selector {
      match_labels = {
        "app" = local.app-name
      }
    }
    template {
      metadata {
        labels = {
          "app" = local.app-name
        }
      }
      spec {
        service_account_name = kubernetes_service_account.dns.metadata.0.name
        container {
          name = local.app-name
          image = "bitnami/external-dns:0.12.1"
          args = [ "--source=service", "--source=ingress", "--provider=azure", "--txt-prefix=externaldns-" ]
          volume_mount {
            name = kubernetes_secret.external_dns_secret.metadata.0.name
            mount_path = "/etc/kubernetes"
            read_only = true
          }
        }
        volume {
          name = kubernetes_secret.external_dns_secret.metadata.0.name
          secret {
            secret_name = kubernetes_secret.external_dns_secret.metadata.0.name
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```